# Django ORM - filter with another table like LEFT JOIN adding a column

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

Well i got a problem with Django i want to acces to all the "Reaccion" but add a column (like in the image) if exists a relationship with "ReaccionPost" including "id_post" ,'status', and id_reaccion, but if it's not exist, in the colum should be a 0 por '' and if exists should be 1 or another true statement,

Thank you for reading my issue.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3suBvZgwQ0JVmtxb1pzbmxGZW8/view?usp=sharing

```
class Reaccion(models.Model):
    nombre  = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    descripcion  = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    icono = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Post(models.Model):
    usuario= models.ForeignKey(User)
    tipo= models.ForeignKey(Tipo)
    creacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Estado,default=1)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.titulo

class ReaccionPost(models.Model):
    ESTADO = (
        (1, 'Activo'),
        (2, 'Inactivo'),
    )
    id_post= models.ForeignKey(Post)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User)
    id_reaccion = models.ForeignKey(Reaccion)
    creacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=ESTADO,default=1)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.usuario) +" "+ str(self.id_post) +" "+ str(self.id_reaccion)
```